# Replacing the Zeros of One List by the (i-1)th Element of Another List

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

My goal is to replace the zeros of one list with the (i-1)th element of a second list. For example, if

```
list1 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
```

and

```
list2 = {6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 10, 8, 11, 3, 5, 0, 12}
```

the desired output is {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}. Note that the first element of the output is defined as 0 still.

My attempt to create a code for this is to first find the zeros of `list1`then run a for-loop for $i \in$`zeroslist1`.

```
zeroslist1 = Flatten[Position[list1, 0]]
 DeleteCases[
 Flatten[Reap@
   Do[Sow[ReplacePart[vtest1, 
      i -> vtest2[[i - 1]] & /@ zeroslist1]], {i, zeroslist1}], 2], Null]
```

The results of the output are:

{{List,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}, {0,1,1,4,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}, {0,1,1,0,7,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,10,1,0,0,1,0}, {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,11,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,3,1,0}, {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}}.

Either a cleaner way to code the desire output or a method of merging the output of my current for-loop to get the desired output would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a multiplication instead of looping or conditionals:

```
list1 + (1 - list1) Prepend[Most[list2], 0]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

The central point is that 0 and 1 in `list1` aren't just symbols but numeric quantities.

Comment: What a simple way to do this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

```
idx = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Rest[list1], 0];
result = list1;
result[[idx + 1]] = list2[[idx]];
result
```

> {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility:

```
Module[{tmp=list1},
    With[{i = Pick[Range[Length[list1]-1], Rest @ list1, 0]},
        tmp[[i+1]]=list2[[i]]
    ];
    tmp
]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Answer (score 3):

Also `MapIndexed` works fine

```
(# /. List -> 0) & /@ MapIndexed[Replace[#1, 0 -> list2[[#2[[1]] - 1]]] &, list1]
```

The first piece just replaces the special case when a zero element is in the first entry (in Mathematica the 0th element is the `Head`, which in this case is `List`). Then the function [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) does its job.

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[If[#1 == 0, #2, #1] &, {Join[list1, {0}], Join[{0}, list2]}] // Most
```

> {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Your answer from above

> {0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};

b = {6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 10, 8, 11, 3, 5, 0, 12};
```

Pre-define positions for better readability

```
p = Rest @ Position[0] @ a;
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[Extract[b, p - 1] &, a, p]
```

{0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Using `ReplacePart`

```
ReplacePart[a, Thread[p -> Extract[b, p - 1]]]
```

{0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
l2 = {6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 10, 8, 11, 3, 5, 0, 12};
```

Using `MapThread` as follows:

```
MapThread[#1 + (1 - #1)*#2 &, {l1, Prepend[0]@l2[[;; -2]]}]

(*{0, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 11, 3, 1, 0}*)
```